# Can an electromagnetic radiation move a charged particle?

Tags: electromagnetism

Since an EM wave has oscillating fields can those changing fields move a charge? If they can or cannot, how do the oscillations behave at a point in a period of time?

Also can it happen that the charge and photon interact? Is this interaction the reason why it moves(absorbing energy) or because of field?

Comment: If an EM wave _couldn't_ move a charge, various types of accelerators would not work. (Such as an RFQ - radio frequency quadrapole accelerator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how metals reflect light. The free electrons oscillate in response to the incoming radiation, thereby radiating an outgoing wave of the same frequency.